# Creating variables in R- two issues

Tags: r, recode

I have two basic questions about new variable creation in R. I will show some code and hopefully someone can help answer these!

```
df0$new <- ifelse(df0$old=="yes",1,0)
```

In this code I am creating a new variable called "new" that is equal to 1 if the variable "old" is equal to yes or is otherwise equal to 0. But in the variable "old" I have missing data (represented as -99, -98, NAN). So how can I account for there being missing values?

The second question is about using an "OR" statement.

```
df0$z <- ifelse(df0$x1=="yes",1,0 | )
```

I want to create a new variable z that is equal to 1 if the participant responds "yes" to any of 5 questions (q1-q5). So I want to code it so it looks like: z = 1 if q1 ==1 OR q2 == 1 OR q3 == 1 OR q4 == 1 OR q5 == 1. If none of q1-q5 equal 1 than I want to set z equal to 0. However this also brings up the issue with the missing values as described up above. Thanks so much!

Comment: The solution depends on what value you want to assign to the new-variable if the old value is missing. Should it be NA or 0?

Comment: What is your data structure? In particular, are the questions `q1 - q5` different vectors? (Also, is it `x1` or `q1`?)

Comment: As for the first issue, `df0$new <- as.integer(df0$old == "yes")` is better.

Comment: Thanks all. @jhvdz If the value is missing in "old" I want it to be missing in "new". The way I currently have it coded is that if it's missing in "old" it gets set to zero in "new" but that's the issue I want to remedy.

Comment: @Rui Barradas. q1-q5 are all separate columns. If any of their values are "yes" then I went the new variable to be a "1". If all the values are missing I want to set z to missing. If all the values are "no" I want to set z to "0". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following.

First, get rid of the `-99, -98` and `NaN`. I am assuming that when, in the question, you write `NAN` you are meaning `NaN`.
Encode `NA` values as `NA`.

```
is.na(df0$old) <- (df0$old %in% c(-99, -98)) | is.nan(df0$old)
```

Now, note that `FALSE/TRUE` are encoded as `0/1` and coerce the logical results to class `integer`.

```
df0$new <- as.integer(df0$old == "yes")
df0$z <- as.integer(q1 == "yes" | q2 == "yes" | q3 == "yes" | q4 == "yes" | q5 == "yes")
```

Comment: This is great thank you. Now suppose I want to code it as 1 or 2 instead of 0 1? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @bvowe Yes, there is. Just add 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for the first part.

```
library(dplyr) #because of left_join function
df1 <- data.frame(old = c("yes", "no"), new = c(1, 0))
df0 <- left_join(df0, df1)
```